# Parsing (or Converting) Buffered Output

Tags: redirection, parsing, stdout, string-manipulation, text-manipulation

If a dynamic, text-based, CLI application doesn't include an option for producing unbuffered text output; what options do I have for parsing said output?

Can it be converted to a more appropriate format somehow?

If perhaps there is some kind of tool or utility I could pipe it through, in order to accomplish this feat, that would be ideal.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for.  It almost sounds like you are looking for the utility `more` or its cousin `less`, which would slow down output long enough for you personally to parse,(aka read) it

Comment: or alternately, if the output isn't text-ish at all, then maybe you'd like to look at it with a hex viewer  `./yourprogram | xxd | less`

Comment: You won't have much luck with this here if you don't include your operating system. "Text-based CLI" is very broad.

Comment: @root well windows has the command line tools that linux has e.g. via gnuwin32 and cygwin

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean. It sounds very strange.. you're saying the tool doesn't produce unbuffered.. so does it produce buffered.  And if so then what's wrong with that. I guess maybe you want to shift through all the buffered output it gives to produce an unbuffered lump that you can pipe. You may be able to pipe e.g. `echo a | dir /p`  so dir/p's "press any key to continue" is pushed iirc.

Comment: @barlop Yes, exactly. For instance: Various utilities will try to produce and/or display; interactive and/or dynamic, buffered, text-based content, etc, etc. This typically presents as a challenge to parse, pipe, print, echo, grep, concatenate, redirect, and so on..